# ViewQuery ViewChildren nested Components

Tags: angular, nested, viewchild, viewchildren

I have a situation like this

```
HereIWantViewChildrenComp   <- @ViewChilren(QueryCmp)  //is undefined :-(
    |       |       |
  AComp   BComp   CComp     <- They are in the View of HereIWantViewChildrenComp
    |       |       |
 QueryCmp QueryCmp QueryCmp <- I want to query these
```

---

How can I get QueryCmp from inside `HereIWantViewChildrenComp`?

Comment: How about creating 3 `@Viewchild` for `AComp`, `BComp`, `CComp` at `HereIWantViewChildrenComp` and then a `@ViewChild` for `QueryCmp` at `AComp`, `BComp`, `CComp` ?

Comment: @SoCo well thats the cumbersome workload im trying to avoid, because I have A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-COMPs (8 in total).